# Branch smart banner not redirecting after button click

Tags: javascript, branch.io, smartbanner

I'm using a Branch SDK with our app and in our website page we have a smart banner to redirect the user to apple store and google play to download our app. The smart banner has worked properly in `Android/Chrome` and `IOS/Safari`, but in `Chrome/IOS` it is not redirecting to apple store when the user click in the button download.

We have used this script in this implementation: https://dev.branch.io/features/smart-banner/guide/

We have changed the Branch_Key as it is requested in the tutorial.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function(b,r,a,n,c,h,_,s,d,k){if(!b[n]||!b[n]._q){for(;s<_.length;)c(h,_[s++]);d=r.createElement(a);d.async=1;d.src="https://cdn.branch.io/branch-latest.min.js";k=r.getElementsByTagName(a)[0];k.parentNode.insertBefore(d,k);b[n]=h}})(window,document,"script","branch",function(b,r){b[r]=function(){b._q.push([r,arguments])}},{_q:[],_v:1},"addListener applyCode banner closeBanner creditHistory credits data deepview deepviewCta first getCode init link logout redeem referrals removeListener sendSMS setIdentity track validateCode".split(" "), 0);
        branch.init('key_live_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', null, null, {referring_link: 'https://bnc.lt/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'});
        branch.banner({
                    icon: 'https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ajinomoto-app/icon-promo-ajinomoto.jpg',
                    title: 'Baixe o aplicativo',
                    description: 'Cadastre-se e participe em 2 passos',
                    downloadAppButtonText: 'Baixar',
                    open_app: true,
                    showWindowsPhone: false,
                    showKindle: false,
                    showDesktop: false,
                    make_new_link: true}, {});
</script>
```

Comment: Alex with Branch here: any chance you could share an example page with the smart banner implemented? If you don't want to post publicly, go ahead and email it to support@branch.io and we'll get this all squared away

Comment: Hi Alex, I made an edition with the script above.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! This looks like it may need some more comprehensive debugging on the back end, so I'm going to forward the details to the Branch support team for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider switching the implementation to [smartbanner.js](https://github.com/ain/smartbanner.js).

It allows Smart Banner to be set up with a dozen of meta tags at 13.2 KB without dependencies, e.g. jQuery.